# Change slide Layout in Powerpoint office.js

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, slide

I am trying to change slide layout of a slide to another layout in slide master. I have this code in VBA but now am looking for same functionality in office.js. I am new to office.js and after going through the documentation for hours I am not able to find anything. Any help will be appreciated.

the VBA equivalent code is.

```
sld.CustomLayout = ActivePresentation.Designs(designindex).SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(layoutindex)
```